# Spring Cloud AWS - EKS and Secret Manager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-eks, spring-cloud-aws

I'm running a spring boot app in EKS/AWS.
How can I, using spring cloud aws, make spring app load properties from AWS secret manager in EKS?
Any sample for EKS/K8S integration?

I haven't used spring cloud aws yet. I've seen samples that does not involve EKS/K8S in pulling properties from secret manager, so I don't know if it is possible and how to make this work with EKS

Comment: WHy not use the Java V2 SDK in a Spring Boot app. https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/secretsmanager/SecretsManagerClient.html

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Import the secrets using

```
spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:/secrets/NAME_OF_YOUR_SECRET
```

Check the documentation https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/index.html#spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager for more details.